# Is there a function to reduce a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Week' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                           'Rabbits' : np.random.randn(8),
                           'Donkeys' : np.random.randn(8) * 4,
                           'Mice'   :  np.random.randn(8) * 4})
```

Which makes `df`:

[image: Example df]

Then I want to group based on the days and perform a basic `corr` test on each day:

```
week_group = df.groupby('Week')
week_group = week_group[df.columns.difference(["Week"])]
week_cor = week_group.corr()
```

Which makes `week_cor` a `MultiIndex` with Week 1, and Week 2:

[image: Donkey MultiIndex]

So, now I want to do the following: I want to create a `DataFrame` based off the "two" `DataFrame`s. To elaborate: Let's treat Week 1 as `df1`, and Week 2 as `df2`. Now let's consider an entry in `df1` `entry1` and an entry in `df2`, `entry2`. The resulting `DataFrame` is constructed as follows:

```
def collapse(entry1, entry2):
    if abs(entry1) >= 0.6 and abs(entry2) >= 0.6:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

So in this case I would want something like:

```
         Donkeys   Mice      Rabbits                              
Donkeys  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
Mice     0.000000  1.000000  0.000000
Rabbits  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

In python I would normally perform a `reduce` a nested list, but it doesn't work:

```
from functools import reduce

def collapse(entry1, entry2):
    if abs(entry1) >= 0.6 and abs(entry2) >= 0.6:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

reduce(collapse, week_cor)
```

Which gives:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'
```

Which makes sense, since it is kind of an array with string keys.

I could be misunderstanding the purpose of `pandas`, but I feel like this idea of performing a `reduce` like operation along a `MultiIndex` would be somewhat common and that `pandas` would have a way to do this. Please correct me if I am wrong about this assumption, and if not, what is the standard way of reducing along a `MultiIndex`?

In general: I am taking a single `DataFrame` and grouping the data by some time point. Then I am performing an operation (in this example `corr`) to get a `MultiIndex` based off of time. I want to "collapse" or reduce the `MultiIndex` in a way similar to `reduce`ing a list in Python. As a result I am reducing the `MultiIndex` to a `DataFrame`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly look for, but to reduce a bit the same way, you probably want to use `groupby` with the parameter `level` and `agg`. In your example, although it is not the fastest way to do it, doing `week_cor.groupby(level=1).agg(lambda x: reduce(collapse,x))` will result to the expected output.

Comment: @Ben.T Oh, that is probably what I want... Haha, I just posted an answer which generalized Dascienz's answer, but your answer seems more concise overall. Definitely worth an answer!

Comment: According to your answer, with the new definition of `collapse`, then `week_cor.groupby(level=1).agg(collapse)` is a good general way, Depending on what the `collapse` function do, because in this case of checking above 0.6, the answer of @ALollz is a better way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I think you can just do another `groupby` on the first level of `week_cor`, checking if all abs values are greater than or equal to 0.6

```
print(week_cor)

               Donkeys      Mice   Rabbits
Week                                      
1    Donkeys  1.000000 -0.118953 -0.235307
     Mice    -0.118953  1.000000  0.803987
     Rabbits -0.235307  0.803987  1.000000
2    Donkeys  1.000000  0.229929 -0.593603
     Mice     0.229929  1.000000 -0.645369
     Rabbits -0.593603 -0.645369  1.000000
```

#### Code:

```
week_cor.groupby(level=1).apply(lambda x: x.abs().ge(0.6).all())  

         Donkeys   Mice  Rabbits
Donkeys     True  False    False
Mice       False   True     True
Rabbits    False   True     True
```

Comment: Nice! That is the conciseness I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Add `.astype(int)` if you need 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1):

So I think the simplest solution for what you want is to drop the MultiIndex using `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index` like so:

```
week_cor = week_cor.reset_index()
```

Now you can select the correlation subset you like by the `Week` column. In this way, you can perform further operations on the two of them more easily. Here's a `numpy` solution, that you might be able to build off of.

```
cols = ['Donkeys','Mice','Rabbits']
df1 = week_cor[week_cor['Week'] == 1][cols].values #ndarray
df2 = week_cor[week_cor['Week'] == 2][cols].values #ndarray

def collapse(A, B):
    return np.where((A >= 0.6) & (B >= 0.6), 1, 0)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(collapse(df1, df2), index=cols, columns=cols)
```

Let me know if you get `reduce` to work, because I'd be interested in knowing.

Answer (score 0):

*Note*: I posted this answer before I saw the comment by Ben.T, his way is more concise and probably should be used.

I am extending Dascienz answer to make it more general:

As Dascienz said:

> So I think the simplest solution for what you want is to drop the MultiIndex using `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`

Thus, from:

```
animal_group = week_cor.reset_index()
```

We get:

[image: Reset Index]

This can be then grouped again by `"level_1"`, so to illustrate (a slice of what this looks like):

```
animal_group = week_cor.reset_index().groupby("level_1")
animal_group.get_group("Donkeys")
```

gives:

[image: Donkey Slice]

This can be reduced using `agg` (although, I'm not sure if this is the best) and the `"Week"` column can just be dropped in the end:

```
from math import floor

def collapse(x):
    x = x.map(lambda elem: 1 if abs(elem) > 0.6 else 0)
    # A little bit of a math trick here...
    return floor(x.abs().sum() / 2)

animal_group.agg(collapse).drop("Week", axis=1)
```

Still seems a little bit verbose (or maybe I am expecting too much from Python). But in the end:

[image: Animal Time Cor]

As desired.